# Keep text in place after header moves back to top the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky header that has a button appear after the user scrolls a little bit. When you click the button, the header moves back up to the top of the page, but the text moves down. How do I keep the text in place after I click the button.

Also, how do I make sure that the text doesn't double the amount of margin between the text and the header after the header moves back to the top. Its somewhat hard to explain, but you can see for yourself. I tried to use `<br>`, but that doesn't work.

```
var closed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 55 && !closed) {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

});
$("div.bottomMenu").on('click', function(){
    $('#header').css('position','static');
    $('div.bottomMenu').hide();
    closed = true;
});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/708/)

Comment: Sounds like something my website does with its nav. if the side navbar of http://www.matutter.com is doing what you want see the git for it https://github.com/matutter/matutterdotcom/blob/master/index.html

Comment: It's moving the text because you are setting the `#header` element to `static` from `fixed`. Thus, you are putting the header element back into the flow of the document. This causes the height of the document to increase. You could offset the page scroll by the height of header element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the `position` to `static` use `absolute` to keep the header out of the flow:

```
$('#header').css('position','absolute');
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/709/

Comment: works great, thanks. i love when it is a simple change.

Comment: I actually passed on this because it wasn't clear from Jacob's example that this is the behavior he wanted. IF this does satisfy your criteria, [then don't forget to set `right` and `left` to avoid getting a nasty horizontal scrollbar](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/711/).

Comment: Good point @crush that scroll is generated by the 100% width and margin on the body tag. Reseting that margin also work and looks better http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/712/